# Getting Multiple Variables to one URL address

Tags: html

I have set up a page that includes 5 different variables that will be chosen by a dropbox in html. I am trying to get the Get QPE button to use all the variables chosen, and insert them into a web address to create a map.  But the url is showing the parameters as "undefined"-
http://nmq.ou.edu/cgi-bin/tools_QPE.cgi?1+0+2+undefined+undefined+undefined+undefined+0+0+34.50+-114.00+32.50+800+632+4101+0+0+1+0+Q2RAD_HSR+Q2RAD_HSR_GC+undefined+english+none+CNTY.  How do I get my selection to be read by the file? Here is code for one of the variables and the JS that I have.

```
<p>QPE - Gauge Adj. Radar<br></p>
Select data ending date, time and timestep:<br>

<form name="SelectURL6" id="SelectURL6">
<select name="ME">
  <option VALUE="1" selected> January </option>
  <option VALUE="2"> February </option>
  <option VALUE="3"> March </option>
  <option VALUE="4"> April </option>
  <option VALUE="5"> May </option>
  <option VALUE="6"> June </option>
  <option VALUE="7"> July </option>
  <option VALUE="8"> August </option>
  <option VALUE="9"> September </option>
  <option VALUE="10"> October </option>
  <option VALUE="11"> November </option>
  <option VALUE="12"> December </option></select>
<select name="DE">
  <option VALUE="1" selected> 1 </option>
  <option VALUE="2"> 2 </option>
  <option VALUE="3"> 3 </option>
  <option VALUE="4"> 4 </option>
  <option VALUE="5"> 5 </option>
  <option VALUE="6"> 6 </option>
  <option VALUE="7"> 7 </option>
  <option VALUE="8"> 8 </option>
  <option VALUE="9"> 9 </option>
  <option VALUE="10"> 10 </option>
  <option VALUE="11"> 11 </option>
  <option VALUE="12"> 12 </option>
  <option VALUE="13"> 13 </option>
  <option VALUE="14"> 14 </option>
  <option VALUE="15"> 15 </option>
  <option VALUE="16"> 16 </option>
  <option VALUE="17"> 17 </option>
  <option VALUE="18"> 18 </option>
  <option VALUE="19"> 19 </option>
  <option VALUE="20"> 20 </option>
  <option VALUE="21"> 21 </option>
  <option VALUE="22"> 22 </option>
  <option VALUE="23"> 23 </option>
  <option VALUE="24"> 24 </option>
  <option VALUE="25"> 25 </option>
  <option VALUE="26"> 26 </option>
  <option VALUE="27"> 27 </option>
  <option VALUE="28"> 28 </option>
  <option VALUE="29"> 29 </option>
  <option VALUE="30"> 30 </option>
  <option VALUE="31"> 31 </option></select>
<select name="YE">
  <option SELECTED value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option></select>
<select name="TE">
  <option VALUE="7" selected>12:00 Midnight</option>                  <option VALUE="8">1:00 AM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="9">2:00 AM</option>
  <option VALUE="10">3:00 AM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="11">4:00 AM</option>
  <option VALUE="12">5:00 AM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="13">6:00 AM</option>
  <option VALUE="14">7:00 AM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="15">8:00 AM</option>
  <option VALUE="16">9:00 AM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="17">10:00 AM</option>
  <option VALUE="18">11:00 AM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="19">12:00 Noon</option>
  <option VALUE="20">1:00 PM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="21">2:00 PM</option>
  <option VALUE="22">3:00 PM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="23">4:00 PM</option>
  <option VALUE="24">5:00 PM</option>
  <option VALUE="0">6:00 PM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="1">7:00 PM</option>
  <option VALUE="2">8:00 PM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="3">9:00 PM</option>
  <option VALUE="4">10:00 PM</option>                  
  <option VALUE="5">11:00 PM</option>
  <option VALUE="6">12:00 PM</option></select>   
<select name="TS">
  <option VALUE="1">1-hour</option>
  <option VALUE="3">3-hour</option>
  <option VALUE="6">6-hour</option>
  <option VALUE="12">12-hours</option>
  <option SELECTED value="24">24-hours</option>
  <option VALUE="48">48-hours</option>
  <option VALUE="72">72-hours</option></select><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Get QPE Map" id="submit">
    </form>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function listen(event, elem, func) {
  if (elem.addEventListener) return elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
  else return elem.attachEvent('on' + event, func);    
}

var form = document.getElementById('SelectURL6'),
    btn = document.getElementById('submit');
listen('click', btn, function() {
    var selectElems = form.getElementsByTagName('select'),
    TE = TE+7;
    if (ME==12 && DE==31 && TE>24){
        return (YE==YE + 1 && ME==1 && DE==1 && TE==TE -24);
    }
    if (DE==31 && TE>24){
        return (ME==ME + 1 && DE==1 && TE==TE - 24);
    }
    if (DE==30 && ME==4 && TE==24){
        return (ME==ME + 1 && DE==1 && TE==TE - 24);
    }
    if (DE=30 && ME==6 && TE==24){
        return (ME=ME + 1 && DE==1 && TE==TE - 24);
    }
    if (DE==30 && ME==9 && TE==24){
        return (ME==ME + 1 && DE==1 && TE==TE - 24);
    }
    if (DE==30 && ME==12 && TE==24){
        return (ME==ME + 1 && DE==1 && TE==TE - 24);
    }
    if (TE>24){
        TE==TE - 24 && DE==DE + 1
    }
    get_qpe(selectElems);
});

function get_qpe(elems) {
    var url = '',
        YE, ME, DE, TE, TS, val = 0,
        names = [],
        thisElem;
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
        thisElem = elems[i];
        names.push(thisElem.getAttribute('name'));
        val = thisElem.options[thisElem.selectedIndex].value;
        switch (names[i]) {
        case 'YE':
            YE = val;
            break;
        case 'ME':               
            ME = val;
            break;
        case 'DE':
            DE = val;
            break;
        case 'TE':
            TE = val;
            break;
        case 'TS':
            TS = val;
            break;
        }
    }
    url = "http://nmq.ou.edu/cgi-bin/tools_QPE.cgi?1+0+2+" + YE + "+" + ME + "+" + DE + "+" + TE + "+0+0+34.50+-114.00+32.50+800+632+4101+0+0+1+0+Q2RAD_HSR_GC+Q2RAD_HSR_GC+" + TS + "+english+none+CNTY";
    window.open(url);
}
    </script>
```

Comment: You're not passing any parameters into your `get_qpe()` function. That's why those variables are being returned as `undefined`.

Comment: How do I pass them to my get_qpe() function?

Comment: What Nick said is correct. You should also look into your <form> tags. You have 2 "<form>" tags inside of your "<form>", no form tags get closed.

Comment: @Chandra_Miller, I just posted an answer. And as Koen mentioned, you should eliminate the child `form` element within your main `form` and you need to close the main `form` with `</form>`.

Comment: I just edited my answer. I was first under the assumption that these parameters could be in any order but then I thought better. Please attempt the newest iteration.

Comment: @Nick - thank you so much for your help.  I was trying the first code and it wasn’t working.  Thank you for the update.  I will try the revised code right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not passing any parameters into your `get_qpe()` function, those variables are being returned as `undefined`. Try this:

Change your button to the following:

```
<input type="submit" value="Get QPE Map" id="submit">
```

And then add the following JavaScript:

```
function listen(event, elem, func) {
  if (elem.addEventListener) elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
  else if (elem.attachEvent) {
    var r = elem.attachEvent("on" + event, func);
    return r;
  }
}

listen('load', window, function() {
  var form = document.getElementById('SelectURL6'),
      btn = document.getElementById('submit');

  function get_qpe(elems) {
    var url = '',
        o = {},
        val = 0,
        names = [],
        thisElem;
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
      thisElem = elems[i];
      names.push(thisElem.getAttribute('name'));
      val = thisElem.options[thisElem.selectedIndex].value;
      o[names[i]] = parseInt(val);
    }
    o.TE = o.TE + 7;
    if (o.ME === 12 && o.DE === 31 && o.TE > 24) {
      o.YE = o.YE + 1;
      o.ME = 1;
      o.DE = 1;
      o.TE = o.TE - 24;
    } else if (o.DE === 31 && o.TE > 24) {
      o.ME = o.ME + 1;
      o.DE = 1;
      o.TE = o.TE - 24;
    } else if (o.DE === 30 && o.ME === 4 && o.TE === 24) {
      o.ME = o.ME + 1;
      o.DE = 1;
      o.TE = o.TE - 24;
    } else if (o.DE === 30 && o.ME === 6 && o.TE === 24) {
      o.ME = o.ME + 1;
      o.DE = 1;
      o.TE = o.TE - 24;
    } else if (o.DE === 30 && o.ME === 9 && o.TE === 24) {
      o.ME = o.ME + 1;
      o.DE = 1;
      o.TE = o.TE - 24;
    } else if (o.DE === 30 && o.ME === 12 && o.TE === 24) {
      o.ME = o.ME + 1;
      o.DE = 1;
      o.TE = o.TE - 24;
    } else if (o.TE > 24) {
      o.TE = o.TE - 24;
      o.DE = o.DE + 1;
    }
    url = "http://nmq.ou.edu/cgi-bin/tools_QPE.cgi?1+0+2+" + o.YE + "+" + o.ME + "+" + o.DE + "+" + o.TE + "+0+0+34.50+-114.00+32.50+800+632+4101+0+0+1+0+Q2RAD_HSR+Q2RAD_HSR_GC+" + o.TS + "+english+none+CNTY";
    window.open(url);
  }
  listen('click', btn, function() {
    var selectElems = form.getElementsByTagName('select'),
        i = 0;
    get_qpe(selectElems);
  });
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dM4Q/7/) that you can reference.

Comment: I am getting a get_qpe() not defined error. The button has onclick="get_qpe()", should that be something different now?

Comment: Let's change your button and add an `id` to it so that we can easily attach a `click` event listener to it. Revising answer now.

Comment: it is reading the correct values from the dropdown boxes but not assigning the right webaddress.  When you click the button the url http://156.42.96.39/alert/Google/docs/raininfo.html?ME=8&DE=15&YE=2012&TE=19&TS=24 comes up.  It needs to be assigning the values to the url string     url = "http://nmq.ou.edu/cgi-bin/tools_QPE.cgi?1+0+2+"+YE+"+"+ME+"+"+DE+"+"+TE+"+0+0+34.50+-114.00+32.50+800+632+4101+0+0+1+0+Q2RAD_HSR+Q2RAD_HSR_GC+"+TS+"+english+none+CNTY";.  Thoughts?  Again, I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: when the url is read correctly it will display a rainfall map like this http://nmq.ou.edu/cgi-bin/tools_QPE.cgi?1+2+2+2012+8+16+11+0+0+34.50+-114.00+32.50+800+632+4101+0+0+1+0+Q2RAD_HSR+Q2RAD_HSR_GC+24+english+none+CNTY

Comment: Duh, I never declared it as a variable. Revised answer. Add the line `selectNames = [],` to your `var` declaration at the top of the `get_qpe()` function.

Comment: selectElem not defined error now and it still isn’t inputting the values for YE, ME, DE, TE, TS into the url it is adding them to the webaddess like this ?ME=8&DE=1&YE=2012&TE=7&TS=24?

Comment: I'm working on it! I should have something very soon. This code wasn't tested but I'm testing it now.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer. Please have a look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dM4Q/1/) that I provided.

Comment: I am going to try it right now - we had a bad flash flood last night and I was in the field all day for work.  Thanks for replying!

Comment: It works, It works, It works!!!!!!!! Yay!  Thank you so much for all of your help!  You are such a life saver!

Comment: That jsFiddle page is awesome!  That is going right into my Favorites!  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: One more question... I have added the code to our webpage - http://www.fcd.maricopa.gov/Rainfall/Raininfo/raininfo_test.aspx.  The button works great in Firefox but IE 7 and 8 nothing happens.  I am not sure where the error is because nothing comes up in the developer tools when I try to debug it. Ideas?

Comment: The only reason this may not work in < IE9 is the event listener. Apparently, my `listen` function is not doing its job. Let me update that function.

Comment: I had to take some unexpected time off work due to a medical condition but now I am back and trying to get this to work.  I tried the new code but it doesnt work in either Firefox or IE.  The original code is at http://www.fcd.maricopa.gov/Rainfall/Raininfo/raininfo_test.aspx it is working in Firefox but not IE.  If have the same code in this html file http://156.42.96.39/alert/Google/docs/raininfo.html.  The button will work on raininfo.html in both browsers but once I save it on our county website as a .aspx file the IE part stops working.

Comment: Is there any thing you know about .aspx files that might be causing this?

Comment: FYI - My pop-up blocker is off and I took the spaces out of the url and it is still not working.

Comment: I was able to get file running correctly on all web browsers Yay!

Comment: Great! I apologize for not responding before .. I hadn't logged in for a few weeks. This is good news. I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: I do have one more quick question that I cant seem to find the answer to anywhere... how do I add some if/then statements to this code? Need to adjust date/time to reflect ZULU time. I think I need to do it in the JavaScript. Need to add: TE = TE+7; if (DE==30 && ME==9 && TE==24){ return (ME==ME + 1 && DE==1 && TE==TE - 24); } if (DE==30 && ME==12 && TE==24){ return (ME==ME + 1 && DE==1 && TE==TE - 24); } if (TE>24){ TE==TE - 24 && DE==DE + 1 }.  I will add the code to my question code above.

Comment: Hi Chandra, I updated my answer as well as the jsFiddle (click the jsFiddle link as the URL was updated). Removed switch statement and instead pushed values to an object (more portable/readable/less variables). I also fixed your if/else conditionals, tested it, seems to be working. Let me know!

Comment: You are a heaven sent angel!!!  Works perfect!  Thank you so much for spending the time on this.  I appreciate your help so much :)